# Sitecore Language used for Display Name of items in a Treelist or Multilist

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

In a Sitecore Treelist or Multilist, items available for selection and items that have been selected are displayed using their Display Name. However, the language version that the Display Name is pulled from is the current Client Language, *not* the currently selected language of the item being edited.

An example illustrates the problem a little better...

We are importing a large amount of content into Sitecore in `en-GB`. We are not creating `en` versions of this content. Authors are logging in with a default content language of en-GB. However, Sitecore Client Language is only available in base `en`. The actual name of these items is not very useful (it's an external system ID), so we want the authors to see the `en-GB` Display Name in Treelist, Multilist, etc. However since their Client Language is `en`, they do not.

I see two potential solutions:

1. Somehow modify or trick the controls into using the currently selected language of the content item when rendering list items. (Preferable)
2. Somehow duplicate the `en` Client Language so we can set the user's Client Language to `en-GB`.

Any ideas on how to execute either solution, or alternative approaches to solving the problem would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does [this](http://sitecoregadgets.blogspot.com/2010/08/language-filtered-multilist-field.html) get you started?

Comment: This got me started on Multilist, thanks! For Treelist, there isn't a clear "Get Items" to override. I had to use a LanguageSwitcher in the Treelist's OnLoad method.

Answer (score 0):

What if you implement the [Language Fallback Item Provider](http://trac.sitecore.net/LanguageFallbackItemProvider) and set `en` to be the fallback language for `en-GB`? That will then show the `en` display name in the case where it doesn't exist for `en-GB`.

Comment: I would need to enable it for the "shell" site and master DB for this to work, right? Couldn't that have undesirable side effects?

Comment: Hmmm, good point. I didn't think about needing it for the `shell` which is exactly your point.